# Call function inside the Axios request (then) [Vuejs]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to call `show` function inside Axios request, My Axios request inside another function as shown below:

My Axios request inside `Myfunction`:

```
axios({
   method: "Get",
   timeout: 3000,
   headers: {
          ..................
   },
   url: "https://XXXXXX/"
})
.then( function(response) {
   console.log(response);

   //Call function
   app.show.bind(response);

})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And function `show` is in the method section:

```
show (workspace_info) { 
   alert("I am here");
},
```

but I got an error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
```

Comment: What is the type of `app.show`?

Comment: where is your app defined..?

Comment: `var app = this;` @MukeshKuma

Comment: `var app = this;` @weirdpanda

Comment: And `this` refers to I am guessing the `window` object. Try doing a `console.log(app.show)` and tell us the output. If it's `undefined`, then you have your problem.

Comment: @weirdpanda yes it's `undefined`, but both functions are inside the method section? how to solve it?

Comment: It means that `.show` isn't a property. Try defining it like `app.show = ...`.

Comment: @weirdpanda I didn't understand? where is the change will be? you mean in the r request I need to rewrite it as `app.show = response`, like this? I need to pass the response to the show function that why I am calling the function inside it .. and another reason is that it will redirect the user to another page when the request is a success. help me :)

Comment: I have added an answer! Take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179793/discussion-between-weirdpanda-and-mohd-ali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple method would be to do this:

```
app.show = function( workspaceInfo ) { // notice the camel case ;) 
    alert( 'I am here!' );
}
```

And then bind it to the app like so:

```
app.show = app.show.bind( this ); // this is something we do a lot in React
```

Finally, you can use it like:

```
app.show( response );
```

Now, remember that you do all the setting up before you actually call the function.

Comment: What if the both function are inside the `method` section?

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in the chat section.

Comment: which one do you mean?

Comment: I just started a chat with you.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179793/discussion-between-weirdpanda-and-mohd-ali

Comment: what if the error message change to `TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`, is there is any other option to solve it?